# `swift build` aborted with "Assertion `isInProgress()' failed."

Tags: swift, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Run `swift build` gives me these error.

```
swift-build: /home/build-user/llbuild/lib/Core/BuildEngine.cpp:250: (anonymous namespace)::BuildEngineImpl::TaskInfo *(anonymous namespace)::BuildEngineImpl::RuleInfo::getPendingTaskInfo(): Assertion `isInProgress()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

#### What I tried

- restart windows.
- run `ps -aux | grep swift`, not found swift process.
- run `swift` and run ps display below.

```
***   708  0.0  0.1 498876 25472 tty2     Sl   13:21   0:00 /home/***/Swift/swift-5.2.4-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04/usr/bin/lldb --repl=-disable-objc-interop -color-diagnostics
***   713  0.0  0.0 146108  7620 tty2     S    13:21   0:00 /home/***/Swift/swift-5.2.4-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04/usr/bin/lldb-server gdbserver --fd=9 --native-regs --setsid
***   720  0.0  0.0   8404   176 tty2     t    13:21   0:00 /home/***/Swift/swift-5.2.4-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04/usr/bin/repl_swift
```

- downloaded Swift 5.2.5 but it didn't work either.

#### Enviroment

- Windows Subsystem for Linux, Ubuntu
- Swift version 5.2.4 (swift-5.2.4-RELEASE) Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned project `.build` directory, then build works fine.

`.build` directory may be broken by VSCode `Swift Development Enviroment` Extension.

Perhaps it seems that sqlite related error is caused by running `swift build` from Electron in `Swift Development Enviroment` Extension.

As a temporary solution, I solved it by emptying "Swift ›Path: Swift_driver_bin" in VS Code settings so that `swift build` is not executed.